# Java Spring Batch - Resource file is not injected into the tasklet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm doing the java examples from the book Spring Batch In Action chapter 1.
In this example, a tasket unzips a zip file. The tasklet receives the zip file path as a job parameter.
I implemented a test method that runs the job and passes the parameters.

```
@StepScope
@Component
public class DecompressTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(DecompressTasklet.class);

    @Value("#{jobParameters['inputResource']}")
    private Resource inputResource;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['targetDirectory']}")
    private String targetDirectory;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['targetFile']}")
    private String targetFile;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        //code here
    }
}   

@Configuration
public class DescompressStep {

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DecompressTasklet decompressTasklet;

    @Bean
    public Step stepDescompress() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get(DescompressStep.class.getSimpleName())
                .tasklet(decompressTasklet)
                .build();

    }
}

@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class ImportProductsJob {

    @Autowired
    private DescompressStep descompressStep;

    @Autowired
    private ReadWriteProductStep readWriteProductStep;

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {

        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("importProductsJob")
                .start(descompressStep.stepDescompress())
                .next(readWriteProductStep.stepReaderWriter())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .build();
    }


}
```

Below is the test code that runs the job

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBatchTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
public class ImportProductsIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;  

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;  

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
    }

    @Test
    public void importProducts() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(defaultJobParameters());
    }

    private JobParameters defaultJobParameters() {
        JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        paramsBuilder.addString("inputResource", "classpath:input/products.zip");
        paramsBuilder.addString("targetDirectory", "./target/importproductsbatch/");
        paramsBuilder.addString("targetFile", "products.txt");
        paramsBuilder.addLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
        return paramsBuilder.toJobParameters();
   }

}
```

The products.zip file is in src/main/resources/input
The problem is that when running the test the error occurs

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.springbatch.inaction.ch01.DecompressTasklet.execute(DecompressTasklet.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
```

I verified that the inputResource property is null. Why does this error occur?

Comment: what exactly is on line 64? what exactly is null here?

Comment: The error is in the line LOGGER.info ("inputResource =>" + inputResource.getFilename ());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your job definition, you have:

```
@Bean
public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {

    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("importProductsJob")
            .start(descompressStep.stepDescompress())
            .next(readWriteProductStep.stepReaderWriter())
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .build();
}
```

The way you are passing steps to `start` and `next` methods is incorrect (I don't even see how this would compile). What you can do is import step configuration classes and inject both steps in your job definition. Something like:

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
@Import({DescompressStep.class, ReadWriteProductStep.class})
public class ImportProductsJob {

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                   Step stepDescompress, Step stepReaderWriter) {

        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("importProductsJob")
                .start(stepDescompress)
                .next(stepReaderWriter)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .build();
    }

}
```